# NoMethodError in Item_categories#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, nomethoderror

I have the next problem:

Showing /Users/felipevelasquez/Desktop/APPS/meetrico2/meetrico-production/app/views/item_categories/_form.html.haml where line #40 raised:

undefined method `cupon_code' for #

Extracted source (around line #40):

```
37:   %p
38:     = f.label :cupon_code, "Codigo de cupon"
39:     %br/
40:     = f.text_field :cupon_code
41:   %p.columns
42:     = f.label :num_tables, "No. Prod:"
43:     %br/
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/item_categories/new.html.haml

Rails.root: /Users/felipevelasquez/Desktop/APPS/meetrico2/meetrico-production
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/item_categories/_form.html.haml:40:in `block in _app_views_item_categories__form_html_haml__1368949097161944936_70115358072760'
app/views/item_categories/_form.html.haml:1:in`_app_views_item_categories__form_html_haml__1368949097161944936_70115358072760'
app/views/item_categories/new.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_item_categories_new_html_haml__3526667596950049714_70115303712400'
config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:13:in`call_with_quiet_assets'

Request

Parameters:

None

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None

I created the field in my db cupon_code, here is my schema:

```
create_table "transactions", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.string   "action"
    t.integer  "amount"
    t.boolean  "success"
    t.string   "authorization"
    t.string   "message"
    t.text     "params"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
    t.integer  "cupon_code"
```

Can anyone see where is the problem?

This is the hole form:

```
= form_for @item_category, html: { class: 'upload-file-or-text'} do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :coworking_space, "Coworking Space"
    %br/
    = select_tag "item_category[coworking_space_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@coworking_spaces, "id", "name", @item_category.coworking_space_id)
  %p
    = f.label :name, "Nombre"
    %br/
    = f.text_field :name, :required=>"required",:title=>"Este campo es obligatorio"
  %p.columns
    = f.label :image_text_url, "Url de Imagen o Icono"
    %br/
    = f.text_area :image_text_url, :size => "40x4", class: 'image-text'
  %p.columns
    = f.label :image_file, "O sube una imagen"
    - if @item_category.image_file?
      %br/
      = image_tag @item_category.image_url, class: 'image-thumb'
      %label
        = f.check_box :remove_image_file, class: 'remove-ckeck'
        Eliminar image?
    %br/
    = f.file_field :image_file, class: 'image-file'
  %p.alert-message.hide
    Debe elegir alguna de estas opciones
  %p
    = f.label :description, "Descripción"
    %br/
    = f.text_area :description, :size => "40x4"
  %p
    = f.label :notification_body, "Cuerpo de Notificacion"
    %br/
    = f.text_area :notification_body, :size => "40x4"
  %p
    = f.check_box :promo_header
    Línea de Producto de la cabecera
  %p
    = f.label :cupon_code, "Codigo de cupon"
    %br/
    = f.text_field :cupon_code
  %p.columns
    = f.label :num_tables, "No. Prod:"
    %br/
    = f.text_field :num_tables
  %p.columns
    = f.label :reserved, "Reservas:"
    %br/
    = f.text_field :reserved
  %p
    = f.label :normal_price, t(:normal_sale_price)
    %label
      = "en #{@item_category.coworking_space.city.currency.name rescue " "}"
    %br/
    = f.text_field :normal_price
  %p.columns
    = f.label :green, "Green:"
    %label
      = "en #{@item_category.coworking_space.city.currency.name rescue " "}"
    %br/
    = f.text_field :green
  %p.columns
    = f.label :green, "Yellow:"
    %label
      = "en #{@item_category.coworking_space.city.currency.name rescue " "}"
    %br/
    = f.text_field :yellow
  %p.columns
    = f.label :green, "Red:"
    %label
      = "en #{@item_category.coworking_space.city.currency.name rescue " "}"
    %br/
    = f.text_field :red
  %p
    = f.label :target_url, t(:target_url)
    %br/
    = f.text_field :target_url
  %p= f.submit
```

Comment: Can you post the whole form?

Comment: did you create and run a migration to add the cupon code?

Comment: Yes, I did, in the table transactions. This is what i did: rails generate migration AddCuponCodeColumnToTransactions cupon_code:integer

Comment: I did post the hole form Rusian, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is transactions part of the @item_category?
All the attributes inside the object @item_category only will be available inside the form_for. If the attributes of transactions are not setup to be accessible from @item_category, it will not work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So i must say in attributes that transactions belong_to item category?

Comment: Yes... if transactions belongs to item categories, it should be `belongs_to` in Transactions model. And finally, if item category has many transactions, it should be explicit in the Item category model ( `has_many :transactions` )